# ssh <host> bash -c 'cmd' , why is first line of output lost?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, raspberry-pi

Why am I losing shell command output? (in this case via ssh to an Ubuntu Raspberry Pi)

```
$ ssh pi@192.168.4.1 bash -l -c 'echo 111'

SSH is enabled and the default password for the 'pi' user has not been changed.
This is a security risk - please login as the 'pi' user and type 'passwd' to set a new password.
```

^^^ does not print 111. It seems like the first line is being lost:

```
$ ssh pi@192.168.4.1 bash -l -c 'echo 111 && echo 222'

SSH is enabled and the default password for the 'pi' user has not been changed.
This is a security risk - please login as the 'pi' user and type 'passwd' to set a new password.


222
```

(-l makes no difference)

It works fine from on the host:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ bash -c 'echo 111'
111
```

Comment: May be useful: [How can I single-quote or escape the whole command line in Bash conveniently?](https://superuser.com/q/1531395/432690)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're losing output because the quoting is wrong.

> ```
> ssh pi@192.168.4.1 bash -l -c 'echo 111'
> ```

What you have here is a call to `bash` with a requirement to execute `echo`. The remaining argument `111` is offered to `bash` but unused. (The result is a blank line.)

What you probably want is one of the following alternatives.

```
ssh pi@192.168.4.1 'echo 111'                 # Shell executing echo

ssh -t pi@192.168.4.1 'echo 111'              # Interactive shell (with `.bashrc`)  executing echo

ssh pi@192.168.4.1 'bash -l -c "echo 111"'    # Shell calling login shell (`.bash_profile`) to execute echo
```

Comment: specifically in the case of SSH, since it joins all the args with spaces and passes that string to the remote shell